# Powershell script is giving error Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have a PowerShell script that is trying to find the subfolders containing certain patterns in the name. Need to access those folders, and need to list all files inside.

The folder is the network folder. I can list the folders. But I am getting an error when I try to list the items inside of them.

When my script is:

```
$Path =  "\\myNetworkPath\myFolder"
$allFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Directory -Filter "*myPattern"  | 
                Select-Object FullName
foreach ($item in $allFolders){
    Write-Output $item }
```

I am getting good results, showing the needed folders:

`\\myNetworkPath\myFolder\myPattern    
\\myNetworkPath\myFolder\Journals\mPattern
\\myNetworkPath\myFolder\TEST2\myPattern`

But when I am trying to read deeper within the founded folders, getting this error :

```
$Path =  "\\myNetworkPath\myFolder"
$allFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Directory -Filter "*myPattern"  | 
              Select-Object FullName
foreach ($item in $allFolders){
    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $item
    Write-Output $allFiles
    }
```

I am getting this error:

**Error occurred
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find path
'C:\WINDOWS\system32@{FullName=\myNetworkPath\myFolder\myPattern}' because does not exist.
...**

What is the reason? How to fix it. For information, running this powershell script from inside of JAMS Scheduler job.

Comment: Get-Childitem -Path $item.fullname

Comment: `Get-Childitem -LiteralPath $item.fullname`. But easier would just be removing the `|Select-Object FullName` and iterate through the `IO.FileSystemInfo` objects.

Comment: Here is also another alternative:

`$Path =  "\\myNetworkPath\myFolder"
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Directory -Filter "*myPattern*" | ForEach-Object {Write-Output $_.FullName}`